# how to check file availability by using sql

Tags: mysql

Is there any possibility to check file availability in a particular location using mysql.

```
SELECT
tsc_uploaded_file_list.increment_id,
tsc_uploaded_file_list.document_id,
tsc_uploaded_file_list.document_category,
tsc_uploaded_file_list.uploaded_date,
tsc_uploaded_file_list.uploaded_time,
tsc_uploaded_file_list.phone_qunatity,
as file_availability  ('available',or 'not available ') in location concat 'tsc_uploaded_file_list.file_name,'.'tsc_uploaded_file_list.file_location'
FROM
tsc_uploaded_file_list
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCtE3.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this -

```
SELECT
fl.increment_id,
fl.document_id,
fl.document_category,
fl.uploaded_date,
fl.uploaded_time,
fl.phone_qunatity,
concat(fl.file_name, 'Available in', fl.file_name)
FROM tsc_uploaded_file_list fl
WHERE fl.file_name = 'Your_name'
AND fl.file_location = 'File_location'
```

Comment: is there any possibility to check whether the file is is available in mentioned location with respect to mentioned file name in the given location

Comment: Can you plz let me know that from where u r loading these values in database?

Comment: if the file is x. xlsx and it is already uploaded to folder F.so i just need to check whether x. xlsx is available in the folder F.